# Central Directory corrupt

Tags: node.js, https, visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service

I tried to deploy my nodejs web app to Azure using Visual Studio Code
Azure App Service -> Deploy to Web App
but i get the error

Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file /tmp/zipdeploy/3e9kpaa2.zip (0.00 MB) to /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted

Central Directory corrupt.